# Где в локальной справке Visual Studio, найти WinAPI FileAPI (там дерево глубокое)?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, документация, справка, msdn

Например FileApi.h (что есть на сайте Microsoft) должен быть и в 2-х ГБ локальной справки (но там только .Net "весь" есть).
Не смотря на то что в оглавлении и указатель, нет нумирации объектов.

1. Очень вероятно, что в оглавление есть эта страница.
2. Самостоятельно выполнил сравние с онлайн-версией, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea, функция fileapi.h->CreateFile, находится в Win32->Data and Storage. При открытии, там перечислены файлы .h В версии локальной, Data and Storage, открывается на имена разделов, которые если все развернуть рекурсивно, то файа fileapi. и функции CreateFile, там нет. При этом в поиске MSDN локальном, можно найти функцию CreateFile, при этом от этого нельзя перейти на дерева ветку, где функции все оситальные из файла fileapi.h

[image: Скриншот справки VisualStudi MSDN]

Скриншоты бы.

Comment: ¿Ну а открыть ветку Data and Storage и просмотреть вложенные разделы не судьба?

Comment: Там нет, если там есть, то скрины нужно показать